# How to redirect pages in subdirectories if a parent page is redirected

Tags: nginx

I'm using wordpress on nginx and I have redirected one page using this:

```
rewrite ^/main-page/ http://www.example.com/new-main-page/ permanent;
```

Problem is that the page has several child pages and and all child links are broken.

Here is an example of the problem:

```
http://www.example.com/main-page/exists-but-is-broken/
```

The above URL doesn't works because the main page now is the `**new-main-page**`

How can I redirect all child pages to the new URL `^/new-main-page/something-here/` using (perhaps a wildcard)?

Comment: Do you just want to capture the text after `/main-page/` and append it to `/new-main-page/` unmodified?

Comment: @RichardSmith yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture the end of the source URI and append it to the end of the target URI, try:

```
rewrite ^/main-page(/.*)?$ http://www.example.com/new-main-page$1 permanent;
```

If the server is `http://www.example.com` (i.e. this is the same server), you can omit that part:

```
rewrite ^/main-page(/.*)?$ /new-main-page$1 permanent;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details. And this [resource on regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html).

Comment: You might want to use `rewrite ^/main-page(/.*)?$ http://...` instead, so that `http://www.example.com/main-page` URL would get redirected too.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Thanks for the suggestion - answer updated